# How to add custom icon in zk button

Tags: button, icons, zk

How to add **<-** in the button and **->**

for example if i have button called **Continue->** and **<-Cancel**

sample button would be for Continue [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) and the CSS `before` and `after` pseudo element selectors to achieve this, which is independent from zk.

```
.z-button.arrow-right-button:after {
    // find your icon in font awesome
    content: "\f061";

    // move and style it as you prefer
    vertical-align: bottom;         
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: rgb(99, 99, 99);

    // stuff necessary to make it work nicely
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: medium;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-rendering: auto;
    transform: translate(0,0);  
}
```

Another possibility using zk's element structure is to manipulate the icon element's style (in case you use an icon for the arrow):

```
.z-button>.z-button-image {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do it something like this:

```
<button iconSclass="z-icon-arrow-right" dir="reverse" />
```